# Axios Request failed with status code 429 but it is working with Postman

Tags: node.js, api, request, axios, postman

I am trying to access this API using `axios` but I am getting error
with status: **429 [ Too many Requests ]**.
I am sending only one requests still getting an error.

BUT when I try to access this url using postman it is working.

```
axios
  .post(
    `https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search-Data?responsive=true&destination=New+York%2C+New+York&latLong=40.75668%2C-73.98647&regionId=178293&startDate=01%2F20%2F2019&endDate=01%2F21%2F2019&rooms=1&adults=2&timezoneOffset=19800000&langid=1033&hsrIdentifier=HSR&page=7`
  )
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result.data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Maybe because you specified the URL with `\`https://www.exp...\`` so try to use `'https://www.exp...'` **single quotes(')** instead.

Comment: still not working 
did you try your self ?

Comment: @ajaykumbhare The problem is not in the quotes or in the way you make the request, the website is the one that is rejecting your connection.
Probe with different forms in node.js the same error always, I can not explain how it does postman or why it works but the code is not the problem if not the site that does not allow that POST.

Comment: okay thanks @ccordon

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue and this happens because of too many requests.

You are probably running the above line inside some loop which is causing this to happen as Axios is firing off all requests simultaneously.

The workaround would be to **await** the response, something like this

```
try {
  const result = await axios.post(`YOUR_URL`, {<Your JSON payload>});
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Please note the above code has to be inside an **async** function.

Answer (score 0):

use [`retry-axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/retry-axios):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const retry = require('retry-axios');

const params = {
  responsive: true,
  destination: 'New+York%2C+New+York',
  latLong: '40.75668%2C-73.98647',
  regionId: 178293, 
  startDate: '01%2F20%2F2019', 
  endDate: '01%2F21%2F2019',  rooms: 1, 
  adults: 2,
  timezoneOffset: 19800000,
  langid: 1033,
  hsrIdentifier: 'HSR',
  page: 7
}

const raxConfig = {
  backoffType: 'exponential',
  onRetryAttempt: (err) => {
    const cfg = rax.getConfig(err);
    const status = err.response.status;
    console.log(` [${status}] Retry attempt #${cfg.currentRetryAttempt}`);
  }
}

axios
  .post(
    'https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search-Data',
    {},
    {
      params,
      raxConfig,
    }
  )
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result.data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```